# How to create a note on a Spreadsheet cell based on the value of the selected cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup

To get this specific function to work, I'm trying it out in a simple test sheet.

I've got two sheets(STATUS and FEBRUARI) in the FEBRUARI sheet I've selected a certain cell. This cell has a value. What I want the script to do is to look at that value, find that value in the STATUS sheet(say it finds it in A1) and return the value in B1 to a cell note in the selected cell in the FEBRUARI sheet. As example: in the cell it says "Project 6" and the cell-note gives info about this project.

This is what I got. This gives me a certain value(-1) but it doesn't seem to matter where i put the lookupvalue.. it always returns -1.

```
    // My Script

function noteSetter() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lookupvalue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("STATUS"); //source sheet
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("FEBRUARI"); //result sheet
  var cellnote = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var lookup = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lc).getValues() //
  var index = lookup.indexOf(lookupvalue)


  cellnote.setNote(index);


  // This part will actually run the script once it's up and running
  function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
  name : "Set cell note",
    functionName : "noteSetter"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Scripts", entries);
};


}
```

Comment: Is the data in "Status" sheet organized in columns for each of you projects? Should the value to match be looked up in a single row (eg. look through all the values in row 1) or the value to match can be anywhere in the "status" sheet?

Comment: Hi! Yes, it's organized in columns. Column 1: Date Column 2: Name Column 3: Add info etc. So the matching value (Project 6 as example) can be found in column 2 and the note should get the value of the same row in column 3. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Yes it does, you can also share a link to the test ss. Removing any sensitive data if any

Comment: Absolutely!

 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KpExh8ioN42fKgnXaY_9t37jGw-1z5oDlrlNXBZtKwM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
  var lookup = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lc).getValues();
  var index = lookup.indexOf(lookupvalue)
```

The first line returns a 2D array.  indexOf() only works on flattened arrays.  Try using:

```
var lookup = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lc).getValues()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to Google preferably use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcurrentcell)  `getCurrentCell()` instead of `getActiveCell()` because it returns the current highlighted (or selected) cell.

Also your `onOpen()` function should be outside of your `noteSetter()` function otherwise it is not being called when the spreadsheet opens.

The following code will do what you want for a sheet like yours. If the data order is altered you have to alter the range formulas accordingly.

```js
/* 
 * This function will run when the Spreadsheet is opened and,
 * will add a Menu item for the noteSetter function 
 */
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Set cell note",
    functionName : "noteSetter"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("My Menu", entries);
};

function noteSetter() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("STATUS"); //source sheet
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("FEBRUARI"); //result sheet
  var noteCell = sheet2.getCurrentCell();
  var lookUpValue = noteCell.getValue();

  // Search through Col C in "STATUS" sheet to get the matching row
  // You need to transpose the lookUpRange 
  var lookUpRange = sheet.getRange(2,3,sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  lookUpRange = transpose(lookUpRange);

  var index = lookUpRange[0].indexOf(lookUpValue);  // Starts at 0
  var row = index + 2;  // One for the omitted header and one because rows start at 1
  var note = sheet.getRange(row,7).getValue();

  noteCell.setNote(note);

}

// You need to transpose to avoid looping through the array
function transpose(a)
{
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}
```

Comment: Oooh sh#t! It's getting somewhere! Cool. The only thing now is that it returns a value to the cell, not to the note of the cell. And it seems that it's not looking at the value of the "current cell" do I need to add a "get value" of the current cell?

Comment: I had a typo in the script, `noteCell.setValue(note);` should be changed to `noteCell.setNote(note);`. Please accept the answer and upvote if it works for you

Comment: But changing:

"notecell.setvalue(note) to noteCell.setNote(note)" returns the value to the note.

Now I only have to adjust the return value.

Comment: What do you mean by "the return value". Which function's return value?

Comment: The "current cell" Project 6 in FEBRUARI is now set to "332514" which matches column 7 of Project 4 in the STATUS sheet.

Comment: Aha! I was missing some offsets for the row. 1 for the omitted header and one because arrays start at index 0 and rows in the sheet start at index 1. It should work as expected now :)

Comment: YOU ARE A FREAKING WIZARD. THANKS SO MUCH. I get the basics, I understand your script when i read it. But I need to get better at tying it together. Thanks again.